# English to Latin translation for tattoo

Tags: motto

So I have 3 phrases I’d like to get translated for possible tattoos. I don’t want them to be wrong since they would be permanent.

1. By myself or for myself, by myself
2. I walk alone or I’m not afraid to walk this world alone.
3. she was whole, all on her own

Or if you guys know any independent/alone Latin quotes :)

Comment: Welcome to the site! I took the liberty to make small polishing edits. Can you elaborate a bit on what you want to mean by those phrases? A literal translation is not always possible, so it's good to know what you actually want to say. Those three are pretty clear, but if there are any tones or connotations you want to have or avoid, please edit that into your question.

Comment: I guess the tone I’m going for is saying it as being independent & strong if that’s what you’re asking. I want the saying to represent me as I like to solve things and like to save myself, and be independent without help from others!

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to put these succinctly — and with a certain compassion about the suffering involved in tattooing! — as follows:

*Ipsi ago* (I act for myself), or *pro me solo* (for me alone, for no-one but me).

*solus eo* (I go alone), or *non timeo inter homines ire* (I do not fear to go among men, *sc*. through the world, through life).

*integra erat ac sola*.

*ire* is a basic verb meaning 'to go' in any sense, which I prefer here to *ambulare*, which is the verb that actually means 'to walk'. Also, for 'the world' I have used *homines*, meaning 'men' or 'mankind', whom you presumably regard as the threat, rather than 'the world' itself.

NB — if you are female, you should change both *solus* and *solo* in the above to *sola*.

Comment: Why not [vado](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvado1) instead of eo? I think it sounds better and is closer in meaning to the original.

Comment: @ Rafael I'm not sure that _solus vado_ sounds any better than _solus eo_, though it would also be correct — but each to his own taste, I suppose!